# Point of sale printing. Align left and aligh right in one row

Tags: java, point-of-sale

Is it possible to use align left and align right in one row? For example Some text "Text 1" Which starts from the left border + some text "Text 2" that is on the same line but aligned to the right? Right now i can only specify where to align text before sending text data to the recipe printer and i can't think of a way how to do it in one line. These are the methods that i use. Or how should i approach this problem?

Align left:

```
 public String alignLeft() {
    final byte[] AlignLeft = {27, 97,48};
    String s = new String(AlignLeft);
    commandSet += s;
    return s;
}
```

Align right:

```
public String alignRight() {
    final byte[] AlignRight = {27, 97,50};
    String s = new String(AlignRight);
    commandSet += s;
    return s;
}
```